# Problem while showing active selection on Wagtail navbar

Tags: javascript, css, django, wagtail

I am trying to highlight the active selection on a navbar in Wagtail. It works if the navbar does not call a new page

```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active"  href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
    </li>
```

But if the link points to a new page,

```
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active"  href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
    </li>
```

the highlight shows until the new page is loaded and then disappears.

My complete code is:

**base.html**

```
{% load static wagtailuserbar %}

<html class="no-js" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        {# Global stylesheets #}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/wagtail_nav.css' %}">
        {% block extra_css %}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/lumen/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/my.css' %}">
        {% endblock %}
    </head>

    <body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
        <div class="container">
            <br>
            <nav class="container-fluid navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark" style="padding-left: 75px; margin-top: -16px;">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"  href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
        </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
        {% block extra_js %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/my.js' %}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**my.css**

```
.navbar-dark .nav-item  .nav-link.active {
color:white;
background-color: green;
}
```

**my.js**

```
$('.navbar-nav .nav-link').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-nav .nav-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

Can anyone show me a workaround?

[Edit 202 06 02 09:18]
My guess is the the 'active' state of the nav-item is being overwritten. I don't know how to reset it